# Is the iOS convention to not indent functions and properties defined within a block?

Tags: ios

Is it iOS convention to not indent properties, functions, etc defined with a block?

For example defining properties within an interface in a .h file looks like this:

```
@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController : UIViewController

@property XYZToDoItem *toDoItem;

@end
```

In the other languages I'm used to (ruby, php, python, js) it would look like this:

```
@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController : UIViewController

    @property XYZToDoItem *toDoItem;

@end
```

Is this the convention? @property is within the @interface block correct?

Comment: The convention is to do whatever the Xcode editor insists on doing.  (While thanking your lucky stars that you're not using the Visual Studio editor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Objective-C interfaces, the definition block is between `@interface` and `@end`. All the properties go there.

The convention is indeed not to indent items in the interface definition.

In particular, it's interesting to have a look at [Google's Objective-C guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml#Properties).

Answer (score -2):

No specific reason its like that, as far as I know. I don't indent. However, you could also do this if you wanted to, and remove the `@property`.

```
@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController : UIViewController {

XYZToDoItem *toDoItem;

}

@end
```

Comment: This is very different from using `@property`. In this case, you just define an instance variable!